# how to send data through serialize form data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

how to send a data for a multiple forms in a page a store a value of particular form through serialize form data.

```
$(function () {
    $('.form').on('submit', function (e) {
    console.log($(".form").serialize( )) ;
        $.post({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'admin/sv_replycomment.php',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $('.form').trigger("reset"); 
                $('#rep_response').html(data);
                }
            });
        e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question, this question has multiple forms, and the other has one form.

Comment: For @pkDeveloper: Create an array: `var theForms = {};`  Then, loop through each form:  `$(".form").each(function(i, e) { theForms.push($(e).serialize()); });` Then, send the data in:  `data: JSON.stringify(theForms)`

Comment: sir i used a code that mentions above but problem in this code is it cannot store a one value it store values equal the number of forms using in a page.

Comment: sir its work but i need to send a value of single form

Comment: Oops, should be `var theForms = [];`

Comment: I clearly don't understand what you're trying to do.  Your question implies that you want to send all forms at once.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to your all forms may have same `class="form"`

So to submit only one form with serialized data, you need to give a unique id to the form you want to submit and `serialize()` data

For example:

```
<form id="type1" class="form">
...
</form>
```

And now your request should be like

```
$(function () {
    $('#type1').on('submit', function (e) {
        $.post({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'admin/sv_replycomment.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $('#type1').trigger("reset"); 
                $('#rep_response').html(data);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

I think this will solve your problem because using class selector will work for all form which have same class

Comment: i also do this but still have a problem it's save four values instead of one.i want to store a one value.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your Code To post all fields data from the FORM to PHP

```
//Ajmal Praveen
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            data: $("form").serialize(),
            ...rest
        });
    });
```

Comment: my problem is that i used it for single form not multiple form its not store a single value